# Firebase update an object inside a nested array

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

In Firestore I have a Document with a property(named "items") of type array. The array contains `ShoppingItem` objects with the following structure:

```
export class ShoppingItem {
 id?: string; 
 name: string;
 checked = false;
}
```

And for the sake of completion, below the document structure:

```
export interface ShoppingList {
 id: string;
 name?: string;
 items: ShoppingItem[]; // <-- This is the array property I am updating
}
```

From the UI, the user can update the `checked` property of the object and I want to update the database accordingly. I read from the Firebase documentation that we can use `arrayRemove/arrayUnion` to atomically remove/add array items.

In order to update an existing item, should I have to remove the old object and add the new one each time (nested promises) like below? Or would it be possible in a more elegant way?

```
updateItem(listId: string, item: ShoppingItem) {
  const docRef = this.db.collection("list").doc(listId)

  return docref.update({ items: firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(item) })
    .then(() => {
    {
      docRef.update({ items: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(item) });
    }
  });
}
```

Another drawback of removing and adding the item inside the array, is that the updated element *flicker* in the UI.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use the same ref to perform the updates on?
Ex: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: No, I could do as in the docs you suggested. It looks a bit better (I updated my questions's code). However in order to be sure the arrayRemove was successful and the promise has not been rejected for any reason, I still need to use the promise "happy path" before adding the new value of the object. However now the code looks better, therefore probably this is the only way to go.

Comment: Hm, I see. I was wondering if the ref refetch was making that happen, but I guess it'll react to both updates. Are you able to pipe the firebase list result and have a "takeWhile" style operator that won't update when you are updating the store? Ex: set a subject to true/false and use that on the firestore fetch for the list

Comment: I can try to implement such a logic to prevent the flickering effect.

Comment: This is creating duplicates for me, not updating the original item in the array

Answer (score 1):

Still, there is no way to update the specific field of an array of objects. (arrayRemove/arrayUnion) is the only solution.